# Как менять выделение заголовка в меню шапки в зависимости от страницы ?

Tags: html, css, header

[image]

В шапке есть меню, в котором выбранная страница выделяется нижней рамкой, как мне имея один CSS файл менять это выделение исходя из страницы ? Т.е. что бы при открытии страницы "Продукция" красная линия была уже под этим пунктом меню ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имея только CSS, этого делать невозможно.. Нужно добавить нужный класс к каждой странице в котором пользователь находится, сделать следующим образом
просто создать класс `.active` где те же самые стили и добавлять активному элементу.

Как например в наипростейшем простейшем примере внизу:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').add(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='active'>Главная</li>
  <li>Продукция</li>
  <li>О нас</li>
  <li>Личный кабинет</li>
</ul>
```

Но для многостраничников желательно выносить меню в отдельный файл и манипулировать им с помощью принятого контекста от сервера.

Comment: А как происходит запоминание элемента, по которому кликнули? откуда другая страница знает, что именно этот элемент меню должен быть активным?

Comment: В другой странице указать данный класс с этим активным меню.. Просто с помощью CSS файла этого сделать невозможно ведь.. Если сайт многостраничный, то хедер желательно поместить в один отдельный файл, и там с помощью принятого от сервера контекста менять меню.. Типа получили контекст menu='main', что-то типа следующего: `<li class="menu {% if menu == 'main' %} active {% endif %}">Главная</li>` и так далее..

Answer (score 0):

Отлично работает, спасибо за помощь!

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').add(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='active'>Главная</li>
  <li>Продукция</li>
  <li>О нас</li>
  <li>Личный кабинет</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если ответ принят, то нажмите на галочку принять ответ.